# How to Monitor Qt application status on Linux

Tags: linux, qt, freeze, system-monitoring

I wrote a application using Qt for a Embedded system, having Ubuntu 10.04.

My application is running 24x7 on monitor connected to my embedded device.

My application UI get hangs some time (I am debugging on this issues).

Mean while is there any tool on Linux which monitor my Qt application.
The monitoring tool will check the status of Qt application and restart it, if it get hanged.

Or is there any other technique to monitor and restart my application on Ubuntu 14.04.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like [watchdog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watchdog_timer) can help you.

Comment: maybe some cron script periodicly checking if its running.. also vrrp comes to my mind (but its rather complicated)